# Kiosk mode WPF app throw Windows Configuration Designer

Tags: wpf, kiosk, windows-10-desktop

I have Windows 10 Ent and WPF app with installer. I want get .ppkg file with configuration this WPF app in kiosk mode, but I get some validation errors in Windows Configuration Designer on the step Configure kiosk account and app. I follow the guides:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/create-a-kiosk-image#shell-launcher
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

**Short. I am doing:**

1. Turn on Shell Launcher in Windows features
2. Install Windows Configuration Designer
3. Set up a kiosk using the kiosk wizard in Windows Configuration Designer (guide 2)
4. I get an error at [step 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEEg7.png)

I try create KioskUser without Win Conf Designer. I try use another standart win app (for example notepad.exe), UWP app (calc). I create a kiosk user account with WCD and without WCD (Settings -> Account -> Family & other people).  Anyway I fail in step 6. I guess the problem can be in the kiosk user.

In the end I want to get the .ppkg file with my WPF app in the kiosk mode.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Setting up kiosk seems to have issues with Windows Store app Windows Configuration Manager. Try using the desktop version included in Windows ADK.